# Possibility of a Theme Change?

Tags: feature-request

Looking throughout the SE world, I see a lot of sites which have themes. What is the transition process for this? Can this only occur when the site transitions away from Beta, or can it occur before this? I have some ideas which may be useful, but I don't know the process. If we could transition to a better (read: less bland) theme, we might become a little bit more looked after, especially those looking on from the SE front page where our site icon gets lost in the sea of blah.

Comment: I think that happens automatically when we 'graduate' from Beta? So we need to make that happen first... Which means we need more questions (2.9/day atm, looks like we need 5)...

Comment: I would doubt the theme happens out of thin air, though, even if it does occur at that point. I was actually hoping for more of a *If you build it, they will come* type attitude, lol.

Comment: True - though looking at the stats, we seem to have loads of people viewing the site - but very few posting questions...

Comment: Very true as well.

Comment: Does anyone know how many questions per day we have at the moment? I would like to see this community 'graduate' from beta. Does the site just need to grow bigger?

Comment: @MaxGoodridge - QPD is currently at ~11.4. We need people to vote, but vote primarily on newbies stuff. We are looking to build our elections voting base by doing so. SE is looking at us for promotion, but we don't have enough voters to have a proper mod election. Read the question in the yellow box to the right about it.

Comment: Lets vote people! @Paulster Yes I saw that question, thanks for the info!